# How to add a background image for TextField in cocos2d-x f

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-x-3.0

I want to add background image for TextField in cocos2d-x for .I surfed all over the internet and could'nt find a viable answer.Is it possible?.If not.Is there an alternative way.Below is the code.

```
userName = TextField::create("","fonts/Marker Felt.ttf",20);
    userName ->ignoreContentAdaptWithSize(false);
    userName->setPosition(Point((visibleSize.width/2)+origin.x,(visibleSize.height/2)+origin.y+90));
    userName ->setContentSize(Size(240, 160));
    userName ->setTextHorizontalAlignment(TextHAlignment::CENTER);
    userName ->setTextVerticalAlignment(TextVAlignment::CENTER);
    userName ->setPlaceHolder("User Name");
    userName ->addEventListener(CC_CALLBACK_2(Login::textFieldEvent, this));
    this->addChild(userName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Text fields in cocos2d have no background property so you have to approach the problem another way. I suggest that you add the background as an `ImageView` & then add the `TextField` on top of it (as a child maybe?) and even wrap the two in a class if you intend to use it in more than one place.

Answer (score 0):

You can not set background image for TextField directly, however you can set background color property for TextField and color as background image pattern.

```
username.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background.png"))
```

(You can also use separate ImageView but you will also need background image same size as textfield. Otherwise it will not fit well as background(like Stretched image).)

Comment: I guess ,you realize the above question I have asked is in c++ and not objective-c and there is no backgound color property for c++